# Normalizing Date(yy-mm-dd) or stick with datetime?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database

We are re-factoring our database, we will be adding about 100.000 rows to the db a day.
Each Row now contains a date field (yy-mm-dd), So today we entered the date "2013-11-29" 100.000 times into a table.

Would it make sense to breakout the dates into a separate table, and use it's id instead since we don't store the time?

There is a trade-of there. If we break it out, we will be adding yet another JOIN to the query used when we want to view the records later. We already join 3 tables when we query for information, The database consist of about  10 million entry.

Any thought? the database is growing huge so we need to thing about disk-space but also preformens.

Comment: No. Not for storage reasons anyway. The `DATE` type is only 3 bytes and an integer is 4, so this will increase the space used. A date dimension is very common in OLAP databases, but not in OLTP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The driving consideration for breaking out the dates into a separate table should not be storage.  This is a question about the data model.  As Gareth points out, the size of the built-in date and the size of the foreign key are about the same.

The real question is whether you need additional information about dates that you cannot readily get from the built-in date functions.  MySQL has a rich set of date functions, where you can get the day of the week, format the dates into strings, extract components, and so on.  In addition, the built in functional also handle comparisons, differences, and adding "intervals" to dates.

If these are sufficient, then use the built-in functions.  On the other hand, if you have "business rules" surrounding dates, then consider another table.  Here are examples of such business rules:

- A special set of dates that might be holidays.  Or worse, country-dependent holidays.
- Special business definitions for "quarter", "year", "week-of-year" and so on.
- The need to support multiple date formats for internationalization purposes.
- Special rules about date types, such as "workday" versus "weekend".

A date table is only one possible solution for handling these issues.  But if you need to support these, then having a separate date table starts to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It probably doesn't make any sense to do this since the storage requirements increase just a bit, and if you ever want to start storing the time, you're sort of stuck.